# Partial linear relaxation yields an integer solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

Consider a binary integer program
\begin{align}
\min \quad &\sum _{j \in J}f_j x_j +\sum _{i \in I} c_i y_i \notag \\
\mbox{s.t.} \quad &\sum _{j \in N_i} x_j \ge 1-y_i, \quad \forall i\in I \notag \\
 &x_j, y_i \in \{0,1\} \notag \\
\end{align}
where $f_i,c_i\ge0$. How do I prove that a linear relaxation of only $x$ variables (i.e. $x_j\ge0$) yields a binary solution? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Note: This is a maximal covering location problem, where $N_i$ is a set of nodes. So, if at least one facility is located in $N_i$ (i.e. $\sum _{j \in N_i} x_j \ge 1$), node $i$ is considered covered (i.e. $y_i=0$). Otherwise, a cost $c_i$ is incurred.

Comment: You have not defined $N_i$. I suspect that is a rather key aspect. And I assume the relaxation is $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision. This is a maximal covering location problem and $N_i$ is a set of nodes. So, if at least one facility is located in $N_i$ (i.e. $\sum _{j \in N_i} x_j \ge 1$), node $i$ is considered covered (i.e. $y_i=0$). Otherwise, a cost $c_j$ is incurred.

Comment: Furthermore: can one make any assumptions about the signs of $f_i$ and/or $c_j$ (e.g., are they positive? nonnegative?) I recommend editing the question itself with these clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be true.

Take $|I| = |J| = 3$, and pick three neighbourhoods, namely $\{1,2\}, \{1, 3\},$ and $\{2,3\}$.  Take $c_i = 50$ for all $i$ and $f_i = 1$ for all $i$.

The optimal solution if we let $x$ be fractional is $x = (\frac12, \frac12, \frac12)$, $y = (0, 0, 0)$, which has objective value $1.5$.  You can check that, if $x$ and $y$ must both be integral, the optimal solution has objective value $2$.

**EDIT**:  However, for a fixed integral $x$, it is quite easy to find an optimal $y$; set $y_i$ to 1 whenever $c_i$ is negative or the corresponding constraint would otherwise be violated; set $y_i$ to zero otherwise.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!